# Dynamic Sidebar Menu in RShiny using renderMenu disappears when another menu item is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinyapps

I am trying to create a dynamic sidebar panel in R Shiny Dashboard. I have successfully added the functionality to add a sidebar menu item based on whether a pre-defined condition satisfied. However, once I click any of the sub-menu items already present in the application, the dynamic content disappears. Following is a working example of the problem:

```
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
                     dashboardSidebar(
                       sidebarMenu(
                         id = "tabss"
                         ,menuItem("General Information", tabName = "General_Information", icon = icon("android"))
                         ,sidebarMenuOutput("dynamic_content")
                         ,menuItem("Settings", tabName = "settings", icon = icon("cogs")
                                   ,menuSubItem("Setting1", tabName = "Setting1", icon = icon("cogs"))
                                   ,menuSubItem("Setting2", tabName = "Setting2", icon = icon("cogs")))
                         )),
                       dashboardBody(
                         tabItems(
                           tabItem("General_Information",
                                   actionButton("add_menuItem",label = "Add Menu Item"))
                         )
                       )
                       )

server <- function (input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$add_menuItem,{
    output$dynamic_content <- renderMenu(menuItem("Dynamic Menu","dynamicMenu"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = c(launch.browser = T))
```

In the example above, using the action button on general information page adds a menu item on side bar panel between general information and setting. However, opening the setting sub-menu causes the dynamically added menu item to disappear from the sidebar.

I am looking for a workaround so that the dynamically created menu item does not disappear. I would welcome and appreciate any help on this. Please let me know if any more information would be helpful for a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could add a `reactiveVal` to contain your extra dynamic menu items. Then, would move your static menu items from `ui` to a `server` method, so you can include with the dynamic items together. Hope this might be helpful.

```
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        id = "tabss"
                        ,sidebarMenuOutput("dynamic_content")
                      )),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem("General_Information",
                                actionButton("add_menuItem",label = "Add Menu Item"))
                      )
                    )
)

server <- function (input, output, session){

  menu_val <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(input$add_menuItem,{
    menu_val(menuItem("Dynamic Menu", "dynamicMenu"))
  })

  output$dynamic_content <- renderMenu({
    menu_list <- list(
      menuItem("General Information", tabName = "General_Information", icon = icon("android")),
      menu_val(),
      menuItem("Settings", tabName = "settings", icon = icon("cogs")
                ,menuSubItem("Setting1", tabName = "Setting1", icon = icon("cogs"))
                ,menuSubItem("Setting2", tabName = "Setting2", icon = icon("cogs")))
    )
    sidebarMenu(.list = menu_list) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben for the quick response. This works perfect. However I am also looking for some explanation as to why this behavior occurred in the first place. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: Glad this worked out...a few additional thoughts...I would avoid using `output$dynamic_content` called within an `observeEvent` (in general, usually not needed). Also, for any nested/complex dynamic `menu` generation I usually see `menu` development with items together in `server`. Adding the dynamic menu content sandwiched between two other `menuItems` this seemed to work better in `renderMenu` when rendered all together. I looked for additional examples elsewhere and this was closest found to other solutions I have come across. I'd be interested to know if others have additional comments.

Comment: In other words...it's a good question, and I wish I had better thoughts on this behavior!